# How to set TObject from TFieldString retrieved from a Firebird table using C++Builder

Tags: casting, firebird, c++builder, tcomport

I am working with the TComPort component by Winsoft. I stored values of some of its properties in a Firebird table and afterwards tried to use them for setting a TComPort instance.

Code is below:

```
// Storing
IBSQL1->SQL->Clear();
IBSQL1->SQL->Add("Update or insert into FBTable1 (IdTable, DeviceName, BaudRate, DataBits, StopBits, Parity, FlowControlDTR, FlowControlRTS, FlowControlXOnXOff, FlowControlXOffLimit, FlowControlXOnLimit)");
IBSQL1->SQL->Add("values (:IdTable, :DeviceName, :BaudRate, :DataBits, :StopBits, :Parity, :FlowControlDTR, :FlowControlRTS, :FlowControlXOnXOff, :FlowControlXOffLimit, :FlowControlXOnLimit) matching (IdTable)");
IBSQL1->ParamByName("IdTable")->Value = ClientDataSet1->FieldByName("IdTable")->AsInteger;
IBSQL1->ParamByName("DeviceName")->Value = ClientDataSet1->FieldByName("DeviceName")->AsString;
IBSQL1->ParamByName("BaudRate")->Value = ClientDataSet1->FieldByName("BaudRate")->AsString;
IBSQL1->ParamByName("DataBits")->Value = ClientDataSet1->FieldByName("DataBits")->AsString;
IBSQL1->ParamByName("StopBits")->Value = ClientDataSet1->FieldByName("StopBits")->AsString;
IBSQL1->ParamByName("Parity")->Value = ClientDataSet1->FieldByName("Parity")->AsString;
IBSQL1->ParamByName("FlowControlDTR")->Value = ClientDataSet1->FieldByName("FlowControlDTR")->AsString;
IBSQL1->ParamByName("FlowControlRTS")->Value = ClientDataSet1->FieldByName("FlowControlRTS")->AsString;
IBSQL1->ParamByName("FlowControlXOnXOff")->Value = ClientDataSet1->FieldByName("FlowControlXOnXOff")->AsString;
IBSQL1->ParamByName("FlowControlXOffLimit")->Value = ClientDataSet1->FieldByName("FlowControlXOffLimit")->AsInteger;
IBSQL1->ParamByName("FlowControlXOnLimit")->Value = ClientDataSet1->FieldByName("FlowControlXOnLimit")->AsInteger;
IBSQL1->ExecQuery(); IBSQL1->Close();

// Setting
IBSQL1->SQL->Clear();
IBSQL1->SQL->Add("Select DeviceName, BaudRate, DataBits, StopBits, Parity, FlowControlDTR, FlowControlRTS, FlowControlXOnXOff, FlowControlXOffLimit, FlowControlXOnLimit from FBTable1");
IBSQL1->SQL->Add("Where IdTable = 1");
IBSQL1->ExecQuery(); IBSQL1->Close();

ComPort1->DeviceName = IBSQL1->FieldByName("DeviceName")->AsString; // Working
ComPort1->BaudRate = static_cast<TBaudRate *>(IBSQL1->FieldByName("BaudRate")->AsString); // Not compiling : Could not convert type 'UnicodeString' into type 'TBaudRate *'
ComPort1->DataBits = static_cast<TDataBits *>(IBSQL1->FieldByName("DataBits")->AsString); // Not compiling : Could not convert type 'UnicodeString' into type 'TDataBits *'
ComPort1->StopBits = static_cast<TStopBits *>(IBSQL1->FieldByName("StopBits")->AsString); // Not compiling Could not convert type 'UnicodeString' into type 'TStopBits *'
ComPort1->Parity = static_cast<TParity *>(IBSQL1->FieldByName("Parity")->AsString); // Not compiling : Could not convert type 'UnicodeString' into type 'TParity *'
ComPort1->FlowControl->DTR = static_cast<TDTRControl *>(IBSQL1->FieldByName("FlowControlDTR")->AsString); // Not compiling : Could not convert type 'UnicodeString' into type 'TDTRControl *'
ComPort1->FlowControl->RTS = static_cast<TRTSControl *>(IBSQL1->FieldByName("FlowControlRTS")->AsString); // Not compiling : Could not convert type 'UnicodeString' into type 'TRTSControl *'
ComPort1->FlowControl->XOnXOff = static_cast<TXOnXOffControl *>(IBSQL1->FieldByName("FlowControlXOnXOff")->AsString); // Not compiling : Could not convert type 'UnicodeString' into type 'TXOnXOffControl *'
ComPort1->FlowControl->XOffLimit = IBSQL1->FieldByName("FlowControlXOffLimit")->AsInteger; // Working
ComPort1->FlowControl->XOnLimit = IBSQL1->FieldByName("FlowControlXOnLimit")->AsInteger; // Working
```

The issue is that I don't manage to feed most of the TComPort properties as they are of different type : TBaudRate for the BaudRate, TDataBits for the DataBits, TDTRControl for the FlowControlDTR, TXOnXOffControl for the FlowControlXOnXOff... I tried Static_cast,  reinterpret_cast and other similar conversion keywords without success.

Any idea to fix the issue?

Comment: It is unclear to me exactly what problem you're having. Can you be more explicit, or if it gives an error, specify the error? I do find it suspicious that you're closing `IBSQL1` immediately after executing the query, that would mean your subsequent attempt to get values from `IBSQL1` shouldn't work (at least, assuming this library conforms to the normal meaning of `Close()`...

Comment: Why are you casting the read DB values into **pointers**? `TBaudRate`, etc are just plain enums, so cast them as-is as integers.  But you are reading them from the DB as strings, so if the DB values don't represent integers then you will have to *parse and convert* them into integers first. What does the DB data actually look like?

Comment: Thank you, Guys, for your comments.
@Remy, in the case of BaudRate property, data is one of the following : brDefault, br50, br75, br110 ... So it seems appropriate to define the table fields type as string.
I tried without pointers, but no more luck!

Comment: @Mark, I completed my question with the compilator error messages.

Comment: @ibouka Unfortunately, I can't help you, but maybe someone else sees this and knows.

Comment: @ibouka If you have an actual string value like `"br50"` then you need to *parse* it into the corresponding integer value (ie, `1`, or whatever `TBaudRate.br50` is defined as), and then you can cast that integer as-is to the actual `TBaudRate` type (not a pointer!). Same with all of the other enum values.

Comment: Thank you so much @Remy. Will try and share the result.

Comment: Finally, I fixed the issue as following. First, by putting the property value in a combobox and then storing its itemindex in a dataset (i.e. `3` instead of `gr50`, for baudrate property). 
Second, I assign the ComPort property in a switch statement using the field value of the corresponding property, namely the former itemindex, to find the appropriate value of the property (i.e. `case 3: ComPort1->baudrate=br50`).
Thanks @Remy for putting me in the track.